# Puzzle about Spring bean lifecycle initialize sequence

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, lifecycle

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    CompatibleGroovyCompiler.init();
    thriftClientProxyRefs = REF_SPLITTER.splitToList(ref);
}

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
}
```

As I understand it, Spring should call my methods in the order

1. `setApplicationContext`
2. `postProcessBeanFactory`
3. `afterPropertiesSet`

but I added some debug printing, and it showed

1. `setApplicationContext`
2. `afterPropertiesSet`
3. `postProcessBeanFactory`

Something made me think that `CompatibleGroovyCompiler.init();` might be what caused this, so I removed that call, and got the order I was expecting.

Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is incomplete.

The `afterPropertiesSet` method is called as soon as the bean is constructed and all dependencies have been injected. This applies to each and every type of bean created.

Your bean is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and it applies to that as well, although this instance/bean is created quite early on because it is needed for processing the `BeanFactory`.

The bean isn't ready until that method is called and after that the bean can be used as a fully initialized `BeanPostProcessor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give some advice on how to override a beandefinition in `postProcessBeanFactory()` call back. For example, class A has a setter `setName()` and i write a  class B which extends A, and override A's `setName()` but when properties injection happens, spring call A's setName not B's.